# Finish observable after executing promise

Tags: java, promise, rxjs, observable

I have to use promise and observable together.

My front end uses Angular and inside my code, I have to use another library which is in JavaScript.

I have to create many requests using this JavaScript library which returns a promise.

```
let pki = new Library();
let signed: Array<string> = []

const AssinaObservable = new Observable((observers) => {
  observers.next(
    tokens.forEach( (value,index) => {
      pki.sign({thumbprint:thumbprint, token: value})
      .success(result => {
        signed.push(result);
      })
    })
  )
});

observers.complete()
return MyObservable;
```

I would like to complete my observable only after executing all the requests inside the foreach.

I have tried many things and I can't find why it finishes before executing all my requests.

pki.sign returns a promise. await is not available with this function.

Comment: It's not at all clear what're you're doing here. What is `tokens` and `MyObservable`? Also: `tokens.forEach` doesn't return anything, so you're not sending anything to `observers.next`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the rxJs operator `forkJoin` to finish an observable after executing multiple promises. Just pass an array of Promises into it and it will call next and complete once all the promises finish. You should handle the promise data in the observable's subscribe.

```
let pki = new Library();
let signed: Array<string> = []

const promises = tokens.map( (value, index) => {
    return pki.sign({thumbprint:thumbprint, token: value});
});

forkJoin(promises)
    .subscribe({
        next: (data) => signed.push(result) // handle next ,
        complete: () => // complete called,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use RxJS `from` function convert the promise to an observable. Correspondingly also use `Array#map` with RxJS `forkJoin` to trigger multiple observables in parallel. It'll return an array of responses.

Try the following

```js
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/operators';

public someFunction(): Observable<any> {
  return forkJoin(
    tokens.map(value => 
      from(pki.sign({thumbprint: thumbprint, token: value}).success())
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: You don't need to convert a promise to an observable if you are using `forkJoin`.  See https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin. `forkJoin` takes in an `ObservableInput` type argument which "extends" a `PromiseLike` type.